# Product shipping banner

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this to display if a product is available for next day delivery

```
function shipping_banner() {
    $product = wc_get_product();

    $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

    switch ( $shipping_class ) {
        case 'next-day':
            echo '<div class="shipping-banner">Available for next day delivery</div>';
            break;
    }
}
```

But instead of text I would like to display a banner image,

Thank you.

Comment: I believe we need a bit more info, for example:
1. Are you having trouble getting this function to run and display where you need it - in other words, finding the correct hook to use this function with? If so, one of these guides may help you: https://businessbloomer.com/category/woocommerce-tips/visual-hook-series/
2. Seems less likely, but are you wondering how to display a banner image? If so you would want to use an img tag most likely, or perhaps style the div with CSS.

Comment: Banner displays fine. But instead of just a text banner I would like to use an image instead

Comment: Is there any problem with just outputting an `<img>` instead of a `<div>`? Or just giving the `shipping-banner` a CSS background image and desired size? For an `<img src="...">`, you can also get an image URL from a WP attachment (media) by id or slug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand and using this image only as an example

[image]

you can just add the URL with the img tag.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yviRS.png" alt="next day delivery" />
```

It would be something like this.

```
function shipping_banner() {
    $product = wc_get_product();

    $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();

    switch ( $shipping_class ) {
        case 'next-day':
            echo '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yviRS.png" alt="next day delivery" />';
            break;
    }
}
```

If it is not working, please show what error display as more info about where you are displaying this or on what hook of WC.